# Compare Current Date with LIKE in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the date field in this format `2016-06-09 10:56:29.000` in one of the table. I want to `select` the records based on the current date like `2016-06-09`. I am trying the below query but not showing any records.

```
select * from dbo.Accounts where createDate like CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
```

I know I am doing something wrong here. Any SQL Expert, please help me.

Comment: A date is not a string. This is like saying give me all the apples that are prime numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `like`.  Just cast the values as a date:

```
select *
from dbo.Accounts
where cast(createDate as date) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE);
```

`like` is a string function.  You should compare dates using a `date` function, such as `=`.  If you use `like`, then the value is implicitly being converted to a string, using whatever localization parameters are in effect.

Comment: Just be careful. While converting to date is the one exception to the rule about applying non-sargable expressions to columns in the where/join clause, and you may still get a seek when you logically shouldn't, [it can still lead to bad things](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea). Even though it's a bit uglier, it is much safer to use `createdDate >= convert(date, getdate()) and createdDate < dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, getdate()));` - and that can be used consistently for any type of date range and across all the date/time types.